# Extract all displayed text from php code

Tags: php, regex, pcre

This is my first post in StackOverflow, and I hope that I'll do my best to respect all the rules :)

I have a file containing PHP code. I'm trying to read the file and to extract only the text that is displayed via the echo lines, without the dynamic content.

Here is a example of PHP code that I'm using for test purpose :

```
some HTML data
<?php
    echo 'OK';
    echo 'OK'.$ko;
    echo $ko.'OK';
    echo $ko.'OK'.$ko.'OK'.$ko;
    echo 'OK'.$ko.'OK'.$ko;
    echo 'OK'.(($data=='toto') ? 'OK' : 'OK2').'OK';
    echo someFunction().'OK';
?>
some HTML data
```

I have no problem to extract the PHP code from the rest of the content via the following regular expression :

```
preg_match_all("~<\\?php(.*?)\\?>~siu", $initialContent, $tMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

But I don't succeed to find how to delete the PHP code from the echo lines, and keep only the static content.
What I'm trying to detect is :

1 The word "echo ";

2 Any content content not starting with a quote, with an equal number of opening and closing parenthesis (if there is), and finishing by a point;
- OR - Any content between quotes (with detection of escaped characters)

4 loop on the step 2 until I reach a ";".

Am I going on the right direction ? Could you please help me regarding the regex that I should use for the step 2 ?

Thanks in advance!

[UPDATE]

I succeeded to match echo content using the following regular expression (I know that it doesn't cover every possible usage of the echo function, but I think it's enough for now) :

```
preg_match_all("~echo ([^'\"]*?((?<!\\\\)['\"])((?:(?!\\2).)+?|(?-3))*?\\2[^'\"]*?);~siu", $initialContent, $tMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Now that I have the content, I must remove any PHP code in order to keep only the static content. I'm planning to use preg_replace to delete this content, but I don't find any regular expression to achieve this goal...

Comment: You could run into so many edge cases doing this, I wouldn't recommend using regexps but rather http://php.net/token_get_all

Comment: there are actually many edge cases, like the fact that echo can be used with brackets `echo('foo');` ect. Can we know what is the goal for this? It could be an XY problem

Comment: The general idea is that I want to send to a translator all the content of my pages.
For the static HTML content no problem, I removed the HTML tags, I'm able to return the placeholders (from the input fields), I have no issue with the error messages etc that have a translation using a DB...
But sometimes, my view have some PHP basic content (like a loop to display the different lines of an array) and it can happen to display text directly from the PHP code.
And of course, I could modify all my views to avoid that but it will take huge time, and regex would be easier :D

Answer (score 0):

When you confront with an issue and you intend to solve it using regular expression, now you have 2 issues :)

```
/['"]([^'"]*)['"]/
```

Hope that Regex can help you to extract data.

Comment: Haha yes that's true. Regular expressions are really painful to write... :(

Thanks for your reply, but I'm looking for something much more exhaustive. For example this does not work if you have escaped quotes, or if your string starts by a single quote and include double quotes inside.
Regarding this part of the regex, I currently use :
((?<!\\)['"])((?:(?!\2).)+?|(?-3))*?\2